# Sending value from array to mqtt in nodered

Tags: nodes, mqtt, node-red

I have the attach debug output from nodered modbus node and i need to send just the data value in the array to mqtt. How do i achieve this with function node?

[image: node-red debug]

I am attaching what i have tried and the debug error, instead of it sending the value to mqtt that is not happening. I am a newbie to this so will appreciate your suggestions. Instead it sending value 36(which is the value of pv1 at the time i took the second screenshot) its returning 0

[image: node-red debug1]

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66227926/edit) the question to show what you have already tried and explain how it didn't work. Stack Overflow expects you to show what you've tried and we will help you fix it, but we will not just provide solutions based on a list of requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so there are a couple things we need for fix.

Firstly the incoming message is passed into a function node as the `msg` object, so you need to use this to access the input data. The path to the first element of the data field in the `payload` would be:

```
msg.payload.data[0]
```

Secondly it is not good practice to create new `msg` objects, it is better to reuse the same input object for the output.

So putting it all together the best solution using a function node would be:

```
msg.payload = msg.payload.data[0];
msg.topic = "emon/deye/pv1`;

return msg;
```

Another solution to this problem would be to use the change node to move the required values around and to set the `msg.topc`

Comment: Thanks a lot this returned the number, however i wanted the name of the value to also be sent as well. This is the current debug:

16/02/2021, 20:23:11node: d727605.006b0a
Load : msg.payload : Object
object
data: array[1]
0: 776
buffer: buffer[2]
16/02/2021, 20:23:11node: a6a7efd2.c10dc
emon/deye/pv1 : msg.payload : number
776

Comment: That's not what you asked in the original question. Do not try and add complex data in comments, edit the question